# Dreamweaver HTML - Column Heights

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm having trouble making two columns expandable while retaining equal heights. I have included snippets from my CSS file and HTML. I have browsed through page after page of similar issues yet nothing seems to work! I know I'm probably forgetting something simple. Below is how my HTML is setup as well as some CSS. Above these tags are the header and nav but I did not think that code was relevant so I didn't post it.

```
<div id="Main">

    <div id="RightColumn-Template">
    <p>Hey</p>
    </div>

    <div id="LeftColumn-Template">
    <br><br><br>
    </div>
    </div>

#container {
width: 1000px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
overflow-y: auto;
}
header {
height: 136px;
width:1000px;
line-height:0px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
nav {
height: 30px;
width: 1000px;
background-color:#219971;
line-height:0px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#Main {
width:1000px;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
clear:both;
}
#RightColumn-Template {
background-image:url(../KeddcoImages/PipeBG.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#A4A7AC;
padding:25px;
width: 200px;
height:100%;
float: left;
}
#LeftColumn-Template {
background-color:#FFF;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
padding:25px;
width:700px;
height:100%;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: do you want equal columns in every condition?

Comment: Every condition? Not sure what that entails, but I would like equal heights for the #RightColumn-Template and #LeftColumn-Template at all times.

Comment: Well its still not clear what you want, better create demo of your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: Okay, I haven't used CodePen before, but I think I've got it. All I want is for the grey box to expand with the rest of the page.http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJZJeN

Comment: can you check my answer? Is that you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. I've given both methods a whirl but it either blows the page out of proportion or makes no difference. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJZJeN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you can use  to create equal height columns.

First one is `Flex Method` using `display:flex`.

```css
div#Main{display:flex;flex-direction: row;}
div#Main >div{border:1px solid gray;width: 50%;
 padding: 10px;}
```

```html
  <div id="Main">

    <div id="RightColumn-Template">
    <p>Hey</p>
      <p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p>
    </div>

    <div id="LeftColumn-Template">
    <p>Hey</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

second method is using `display:table` for parent element and `display:table-cell` for child element.

```css
div#Main{display:table;}
div#Main >div{border:1px solid gray;width: 50%;
 padding: 10px;display:table-cell;}
```

```html
  <div id="Main">

    <div id="RightColumn-Template">
    <p>Hey</p>
      <p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p><p>Hey</p>
    </div>

    <div id="LeftColumn-Template">
    <p>Hey</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```